# Rails: Add Variable to Model (or Controller) Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to add a new variable (method) to my database query in rails.  I don't want to add a new field to the database, I want to take an existing column and play with it to create a new method.  However, it's not throwing an error or anything, it's just not available.  Any ideas?

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :old_field, :new_field

  def after_initialize
    self.new_field = :old_field * 2
  end  
end
```

Partially, I'm not sure if this logic goes in the model or the controller.

Comment: You want to add attribute(column)?

Comment: No, it's not a new column, just a new method that I want to create based on logic and a separate database column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :old_field

  def new_field()
    self.old_field * 2
  end  
end
```

or u can do it this way, which requires you to add the field to your datatable using a migration like  Anatoliy did below

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :old_field, :new_field
  before_save :calc_new_field

  private
    def calc_new_field
      self.new_field = self.old_old_field * 2
    end  
end
```

Comment: I can call it, and it shows up, but it doesn't show up in my debug @tasks, or in my backbone .to_json.  Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure about the debugging I'm still relatively fresh to ruby. And I have never used back_bone.js

Comment: basically it's not showing up in the overall variable if I just show it -- it's only showing up if I call it.  I want it to show up when I pass the entire variable to an argument, ie `tasks: #{raw @tasks.to_json}`.  debug is (in my naive mind) PHP's `print_r` for Ruby.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @jake I have updated with a solution that you might like better.

Comment: Hmm... interesting approach -- but I don't want to create more columns in the database if they're calculated.  I think what I want to do is add an ATTRIBUTE to my task, is that possible?  I was confused as it's the same syntax for a method and attribute (is that rails, or ruby?).

Comment: does to_json(:only => :new_field)  return a values?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21284/discussion-between-jake-and-antarr-byrd)

Comment: in case anyone else is having this problem, modify your to_json to `to_json(:methods => :new_field)`

Answer (score 0):

To add virtual attribute you should use `attr_accessor` not `attr_accesible`

Try this in terminal to add new attribute:

```
rails g migration AddNewFieldToTasks new_field:integer
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific: I don't want to add a new column, just want to add a new method from logic.